# Array loop with 1 entry

Tags: excel, vba

My array comes from a range which can have a variable number of entries.

```
Dim myArray as Variant, elem as Variant 

myArray = hSheet.Range("A1:A" & hSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
```

I'm using this array to loop through it's values and do something.

```
For Each elem In myArray
    Magic
Next elem
```

This works pretty well when my array has more than 1 value (range has more than 1 entry). However, when there's only 1 value/entry it gives a "Type Mismatch" error.

[image]

I need this to be flexible and work with multiple values, but also with 1 value only.
If you have other suggestions beside an array I'm all ears.

Comment: Before the for each add the line ' If Not IsArray(myarray) then myArray=array(myarray)

Comment: @freeflow this will result in a one dimensional array while reading a range is two dimensional. So this might be dangerous as you then have 2 different kind of arrays!

Comment: @PEH The line of code I propose only functions if myArray is not an array so I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @freeflow What the OP did is `myArray = Range("A1:A5").Value` and this results in a two dimensional array `myArray(row, column)` but what you did results in a one dimensional array `myArray(index)`. So you end up with 2 different kind of arrays for these 2 cases.

Comment: @PEH And this is a confusing (and IMHO wrong) behaviour because A1:A5 is a 1 dimensional array. Hence my suggestion that the transpose function be used when getting the range so that you end up with a 1 dimensional variant array rather than a pseudo 2 dimensional array.

Comment: @freeflow Actually no transpose was used by the OP nor by you. And this is the correct behavior. A range to array conversion **always** results in a 2 demensional array no matter how many rows/columns they have. And this makes totally sense because you can handle arrays form one column ranges the exact same way as arrays from multi column ranges (no code changes needed then). 2 dimensional arrays are the result of all ranges, unless you modify them with transpose (which was not the case in this question).

Comment: @PEH getting 2D arrays when the request is for a 1D array is IMHO a wrong behaviour.  Excel should correct this wrong behaviour by making getting a 2d range an option or a different method so as to be more transparent about the different behaviours/results.  This discussion has little to do with the OP question which was about the issue of getting a single value when a range/array was expected.  An example where your assertion of always getting a 2d array fails.

Comment: @freeflow No it is not wrong. A range is **always** defined by 2 dimensions (rows and columns) even if there is only one column: It is a range object where the amount of columns is `1` (but that does not remove that second dimension).  That is because also a column is a range object. You can only declare a variable `As Range` but not `As Column`. Culumns are also just ranges, and 1-dimensional ranges do not exist by definition of the range object. The rules are `Range().Value` returns a single value if the range has only one cell and a 2-dimensional array in case of multiple cells.

Comment: @PEH you are explaining how Excel currently operates.  That's fine.  I'm saying that this mechanism is a wrong behaviour no matter how long it has been in place..  Range should return a single cell if that is what is specified, a single dimension array for a row or column if that is what is specified and a 2d array for  a range with rows and columns (where rows and columns >1).  IMHO Excel should offer a Range2 method which returns a programmatically convenient object which is always a 2d array irrespective if the range is a single cell or a range with multiple rows and columns.

Comment: @freeflow Well, it doesn't matter what you think Excel *should* do. It works exactly as I said and it will not change that behavior in the future as this would break compatibility. So you have to deal with it I guess.

Comment: @PEH if people don't give feedback on things how do you expect improvements to occur?  The fact that I understand how Excel works and can identify those occasions where Excel doesn't give me what I asked for allows me to write more robust/transparent code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227595/discussion-between-p-and-freeflow).

Comment: @PEH No You indicated it doesn't matter what I think.  That viewpoint is not conducive to a productive discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you `Dim myArray as Variant` the variable `myArray` can be a also a simple value (not an array). So if there is only on cell like

```
myArray = Range("A1")
```

then it is no array but a value and therefore has no elements to loop through.

If you use the [VarType function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function) to `Debug.Print VarType(myArray)` you will see it:

- After `myArray = Range("A1")` it returns eg
  `VarType = 8` (`vbString`) or `5` (`vbDouble`) which means it is a value
- After `myArray = Range("A1:A5")` it returns eg
  `VarType = 8204` = `8192 + 12` (`vbArray` + `vbVariant`)

So you need to distinguish both types and do different things with them:

```
If VarType(myArray) >= 8192 Then 'is array
    Debug.Print Join(myArray, ";")  'print whole array
Else
    Debug.Print myArray  'print single value
End If
```

---

#### Second solution

Note that with `Dim myArray() as Variant` you can force the variable to always be an array. But then putting a simple value (single cell) `myArray = Range("A1")` will fail with a type mismatch error.

So you need to fill the variable `myArray` differently:

```
Dim myArray() as Variant 'forced to be an array!

Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = hSheet.Range("A1:A" & hSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

If MyRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then 'is array
    myArray = MyRange.Value
Else
    'create an array with only one item
    ReDim myArray(1 To 1, 1 To 1) As Variant
    myArray(1, 1) = MyRange.Value
End If

'now you can always loop even if only one cell was in the range
For Each elem In myArray
    Magic
Next elem
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement `myArray = hSheet.Range("A1:A" & hSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)` is equivalent to (IMO cleaner)

```
Dim numRows as Long
numRows = hSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim myArray as Variant
myArray = hSheet.Range("A1").Resize(numRows,1).Value2
```

which returns a nice 2d array when `numRows>1`. The result is the same shape as

```
ReDim myArray(1 to numRows, 1 to 1)
```

**But** when `numRows=1` the result is just a value. Not a 2D array, not a 1D array, but a single value. In order to take care of this case, modify the code above as follows:

```
Dim numRows as Long
numRows = hSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim myArray as Variant
if numRows>1 Then
    myArray = hSheet.Range("A1").Resize(numRows,1).Value2
Else
    ReDim myArray(1 to 1, 1 to 1)
    myArray(1,1) = hSheet.Range("A1").Resize(numRows,1).Value2
End If
```

From this point on, `myArray` is guaranteed to contain a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

In the OP code the nested loops fail when the range evaluates to a single cell.  In this manner Excel is performing according to its specification.  That doesn't stop the error from being annoying.

In my previous comments I make the observation that Excel does not behave orthogonally in that if a range evaluates to a single row or column you actually get a 2d array i.e one of the dimensions is scoped as 1 to 1.

The code below attempts to reconcile the above observations by allowing a range to return a 2D array even if the range evaluates to a single cell.  Additionally, the optional parameter allows for a value to be returned that represents the true size of the range, a single cell returns a single value, a single row or column returns a 1 dimensional array etc.

It should be noted that when the optional variable is False, and a single dimensioned array is returned, you lose the orientation of the original range.

In the test below, the nested loop runs correctly even though the range specifies a single cell.

```
Public Sub ttest()

    Dim myVar As Variant
    myVar = GetRange(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Item(1).Range("A1:A1"))
    
    Dim myRow As Long
    For myRow = LBound(myVar, 1) To UBound(myVar, 1)
    
        Dim myCOl As Long
        For myCOl = LBound(myVar, 2) To UBound(myVar, 2)
        
            Debug.Print "Row "; myRow, "Col "; myCOl, " is ", myVar(myRow, myCOl)
            
        Next
        
    Next

End Sub

Public Function GetRange(ByVal ipRange As Excel.Range, Optional ByVal RangeAsTable As Boolean = True) As Variant
    
    If RangeAsTable Then
    
        GetRange = GetRangeAsTable(ipRange)
        
    Else
    
        GetRange = GetRangeAsSized(ipRange)
        
    End If
    
End Function
    
    
Private Function GetRangeAsTable(ByVal ipRange As Excel.Range) As Variant

    Dim myArray As Variant
    
    If ipRange Is Nothing Then
    
        ReDim myArray(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        GetRangeAsTable = myArray
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
    Dim xlArray As Variant
    xlArray = ipRange.Value
    
    If Not IsArray(xlArray) Then
    
        ReDim myArray(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        myArray(1, 1) = xlArray
        GetRangeAsTable = myArray
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
    GetRangeAsTable = xlArray
    
End Function

Private Function GetRangeAsSized(ByVal ipRange As Excel.Range) As Variant

    Dim xlArray As Variant
    xlArray = ipRange.Value
    
    If Not IsArray(xlArray) Then
    
        GetRangeAsSized = xlArray
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
    If UBound(xlArray, 1) = 1 Or UBound(xlArray, 2) = 1 Then
    
        GetRangeAsSized = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(xlArray)
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
    GetRangeAsSized = xlArray

End Function

Probably not the neatest or most efficient code but at least it demonstrates the point, and, more importantly, allows the OP to use a nested loop even if the range is a single cell.
```